# AngularJS change single URL parameter on load if it matches a value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, parameters, angular-ui-router

I'm working on a web app where parameters get passed to views as you navigate through the site. These parameters are set by user filters.

I've hit a problem whereby some views don't support a specific value from one of the filters, and where this happens the parameter needs to be reset to one out of two possibilities.

I've been using `$location.search({ type: "blue" })` but I've realised that if there are other parameters in the url/on the view, these get removed in place for just the one that is set using that code.

Basically, on some views if the `type` parameter is `all` it needs to change to `blue`, and on others it would need to change to `red`.

Unfortunately this parameter is set in the link by the current filter that is applied, so its not as simple as just changing the href.

You can see here in this example I'm trying to change views that can only be set as `red` to `red` when coming from a view where `blue` was set (and in the link) using an array of paths.

```
for (let i = 0; i < redOnlyViews.length; i++) {
  if (newUrl.indexOf(redOnlyViews[i]) > -1 && type === "blue") {
      $location.path("/" + redOnlyViews[i]).search({type: "red"});
   }
 }
```

(this is inside a `$rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function (event, newUrl, oldUrl)` function)

If there is a way of changing a parameter like this whilst not changing any of the other parameters that would be fantastic!

Hope this makes sense and thanks :)

*changed things to colours for anonymity, I'm not mad :)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set a single search parameter you can do

```
$location.search(angular.extend($location.search(), {type: 'red'}))
```

Comment: Great! Thank you @rob

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, for these kind of situation, `$routeParams` are used to extract the dynamic parameters entered in the url.

It works like this:

1. In the HTML page the Anchor tag where the URL is formed will add the dynamic parameter to the URL like this:

Here the `{{ }}` takes care of added the value of `{{yourModelName.yourModelAttributeKeyName}}` to the URL

2. Then in the `$routeProvider` configuration, in the `.when()` method, the path parameter of the URL must to set like in this case:

`myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

```
.when('/showColor/:yourModelAttributeValue', {
    templateUrl : 'showColor.html'
});
```

});`

3. You can keep on adding parameters like :

and then also update the `.when()` method accordingly:

```
.when('/showColor/:yourModelAttributeValue/:yourModelAttributeAnotherValue', {
    templateUrl : 'showAnotherColor.html'
});
```

4. Finally in the controller, you can extract the `:pathParams` like :

   $scope.firstColor = $routeParams.yourModelAttributeValue;

   $scope.secondColor = $routeParams.yourModelAttributeAnotherValue;

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, but it's not what I was looking for - we have $routeProvider set up as you said but with specific paths, there can be any number of parameters passed from view to view so putting these in the routes would not make sense.

With the answer above by @rob, I am able to simply loop over an array of specific paths and modify a specific parameter if it matches a criteria.