# Add or update current URL parameter using angular's $location

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, parameters

I have a page with multiple parameters in my URL. I am trying to write a function to use on the click of an element. I want it to check if parameter pthree exists. If it does, update it to a new value (not duplicate it). If it does not exist, append it to my current URL and reload the page.

I am running into an issue when I try to update the current URL.

My current URL structure:

> mypage?pone=99.9999999&ptwo=-44.4444444&pthree=1&pfour=1&pfive=1

Controller snippet:

```
$scope.test = function (){
   $location.search('pthree', 0);
}
```

This partially works. It updates my URL, but it adds #?pthree=0 to the end of my current URL.

The result I would like instead is:

> mypage?pone=99.9999999&ptwo=-44.4444444&pthree=0&pfour=1&pfive=1

Any thoughts on what I could do to get my desired result? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you might want to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38206805/angularjs-change-single-url-parameter-on-load-if-it-matches-a-value?rq=1

Comment: Hi @Vinny. I tried the accepted answer from the URL you provided and I am still getting the #?pthree=0 added to the end of my current URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what worked for me. I found that I needed to set the HTML5 mode of my app. Read more about HTML5 mode here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location.

After this, I ran into another issue when calling $location.search({ pThree: '0' }. It started writing over all of my other parameters. For example, the URL structure was changing to ?pThree=0. To solve this I had to read all parameters, update pThree, and then write all back.

I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this pretty easily by just doing:

```
// existing url with params
// http://myurl.com/path/view/etc?param1=abc&param2=def

// add your new param to the search() object
$location.search().param3 = 'ghi';

// set your search again with the updated search object
$location.search( $location.search() );
```

This will update your url like so:

```
// http://myurl.com/path/view/etc?param1=abc&param2=def&param3=ghi
```